# SQL Azure Random Timeout

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, azure-sql-database

I have web apps right now is connecting to the SQL Azure,
Right now  i have an issue on this line of code

> _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result;

The issue is very randomly happen. My Connection Timeout: 300, I have increase to 1000 also not working

> System.AggregateException
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=One or more errors occurred. (Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.))
>     Source=System.Private.CoreLib
>     StackTrace:
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at Panda.LMS.Web.Controllers.Api.QuestionController.ValidateAnswer(ValidateAnswerModel input) in C:+Beta\LMS2\LMS\Panda.LMS.Web\Controllers\Api\QuestionController.cs:line 62
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<g__Logged|12_1>d.MoveNext()
>
> Inner Exception 1:
>   SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
>   A transport-level error has occurred when receiving results from the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - The group or resource is not in the correct state to perform the requested operation.)
>
> Inner Exception 2:
>   Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out.

Comment: Can this be a thread issue ? var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);

Comment: From the error I encounter is mention sql timeout, I make the code is sync var user = _userManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.

The issue is very difficult to simulate, cause most of the time is fine, maybe from 20-50 request to the api it only encounter 1 timeout.

Comment: I had a similar issue at some point in time, and it was causing by the await that's why i proposed it....